# Receive byte[] using ByteArrayInputStream from a socket

Tags: java, sockets, io, inputstream, bytearrayinputstream

Here is the code but got error:

```
bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

Is it possible to receive `byte[]` using `ByteArrayInputStream` from a socket?

Comment: *"but got error:"* Got what error?  Always copy/paste exception & error output into the question (using code tags).

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. A ByteArrayInputStream reads bytes from a byte array. If you want to read from a socket you can't read from an array of bytes. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No. You use `ByteArrayInputStream` when you have an array of bytes, and you want to read from the array as if it were a file. If you just want to read arrays of bytes from the socket, do this:

```
InputStream stream = socket.getInputStream();
byte[] data = new byte[100];
int count = stream.read(data);
```

The variable `count` will contain the number of bytes actually read, and the data will of course be in the array `data`.

Comment: Whats the significance of the number 100 in "new byte[100]"
Will I over allocate or underallocate with the 100

Comment: It’s the size of the array, hence the maximum number of bytes that’ll be read at once. You can use any size you like, and you can read in a loop until you hit the end of the file (count will become -1 at that point.)

Comment: Thanks @Ernest. That Makes sense

Answer (score 11):

You can't get an instance of `ByteArrayInputStream` by reading directly from socket.
You require to read first and find byte content.
Then use it to create an instance of `ByteArrayInputStream`.

```
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();  

// read from the stream  
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
byte[] content = new byte[ 2048 ];  
int bytesRead = -1;  
while( ( bytesRead = inputStream.read( content ) ) != -1 ) {  
    baos.write( content, 0, bytesRead );  
} // while
```

Now, as you have baos in hand, I don't think you still need a `bais` instance.
But, to make it complete,
you can generate byte array input stream as below

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( baos.toByteArray() );
```